# Get most frequent value per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (DeviceOS2) and would like to get the most frequent value for each column (OS and Device) per ID.

```
ID      OS      Device

123     OSX     Mac 
123     OSX     PC  
123     OSX     PC  
123     Android Tablet
```

Desired result:

```
ID      OS      Device

123     OSX     PC
```

However, my code now gets me the following:

```
ID       OS            Device

123      Android       Tablet
123      OSX           Mac
123      OSX           PC
```

Looks like it picks up every combination.

Current code (T-SQL):

```
Select 
ID,
OS,
Device

FROM(
Select 
ID,
OS,
Device
FROM DeviceOS2
Group By ID,OS,Device) a 
Group By ID,OS,Device
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select top 1 with ties a.ID, a.OS,a.Device
from (
select d.ID, d.OS, d.Device, ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by d.OS, d.Device order by id) rnk
from DeviceOS2 d)a
order by a.rnk desc
```

**Update**

If you need the most frequent one for each ID:

```
select c.ID,c.OS,c.Device from (
select d.ID, d.OS, d.Device, ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by d.id, d.OS, d.Device order by id) rnk
from DeviceOS2 d)c
join 
(
select  a.ID,max(a.rnk) AS rnk
from (
select d.ID, d.OS, d.Device, ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by d.id, d.OS, d.Device order by id) rnk
from DeviceOS2 d)a
group by a.ID) a
on c.ID = a.ID and a.rnk = c.rnk
```

Comment: Thank you! However, in my real data I have many IDs. How can I get this result for every ID I have please. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM tab
ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER(PARITIION BY ID,OS) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called the *mode*.  You can use window functions:

```
select o.*
from (select os, device, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by os order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from DeviceOS2
      group by os, device
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want the most frequent combination, then use:

```
select os, device, count(*) as cnt
from DeviceOS2
group by os, device
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

(or use `select top (1)` if you prefer).

EDIT:

For your edited question:

```
select o.*
from (select os, device, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by os order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from DeviceOS2
      group by os, device
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want the most frequent combination, then the query is a bit more complicated.  One method is two aggregations:

```
select o.id,
       max(case case when o.seqnum = 1 then os end) as most_frequent_os,
      max(case case when d.seqnum = 1 then device end) as most_frequent_device
from (select id, os, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from DeviceOS2
      group by id, os
     ) o join
     (select id, device, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from DeviceOS2
      group by id, device
     ) d
     on d.id = o.id
```

Comment: Thanks! However, when I run it, I also get a row with `Android Tablet`. How can I only get   `OSX     PC`  please.

Comment: @apples-oranges . . . I interpreted the question as the most frequent device for each os.

Comment: Ah okay! Thanks mate :-) Final follow up please: How to get the most frequent value for each individual column, per `ID` (in my example only a single `ID` shown). So for `ID` `123`,  `OSX` is the most frequent `OS`. Similarly  for `Device`, the most frequent one is `PC`. Hence resulting table is `OSX PC` for `ID` `123`. Thanks again! :-)